# Error Msg 102, Level 15 There is an issue with my Table alias

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting syntax error near ')'.  I do have an alias for the subquery, The alias is Y. Msg 102, Level 15, state 1.

This query worked before I added a left join from the table dq.JDA_SUPERSESSION. I added this left join into 3 spots for each Union ALL.

```
SELECT

                     Y.Legacy_Company

                     ,Y.ITEM

                     ,C.DESCRIPTN

                     ,C.SIZE

                     ,CASE

                           WHEN C.SUBGROUP_NAME = ''

                                  THEN C.BRAND_NAME

                           ELSE C.SUBGROUP_NAME

                           END SUB_GROUP_DESC

                     ,CASE

                           WHEN C.GROUP_NAME = ''

                                  THEN (

                                         CASE

                                                WHEN C.SUBGROUP_NAME = ''

                                                       THEN C.BRAND_NAME

                                                ELSE C.SUBGROUP_NAME

                                         END

                                  )

                           ELSE C.GROUP_NAME

                     END GROUP_DESC

                     ,CASE

                           WHEN C.SUPERGROUP_NAME IS NULL

                                 THEN (

                                         CASE

                                                WHEN C.GROUP_NAME = ''

                                                       THEN (

                                                              CASE

                                                                     WHEN C.SUBGROUP_NAME = ''

                                                                           THEN C.BRAND_NAME

                                                                     ELSE C.SUBGROUP_NAME

                                                              END

                                                       )

                                                ELSE C.GROUP_NAME

                                         END

                                  )

                           ELSE C.SUPERGROUP_NAME

                     END SUPER_GROUP_DESC

                     ,C.SCC

                     ,Y.Site_State

                     ,Y.Location_ID

                    -- ,D.GS_inco

                     ,Y.Site_Nbr

                     ,Year(Y.Posting_period) * 100 + Month(Y.Posting_period) AS Posting_Period

                     ,Y.Qtytype

                     ,Y.OTC_STATUS

                     ,Y.ABC_CODE

                     ,Y.Qty



                     --  ,C1.Liters

                     --  ,C1.BTTLS_PCAS

                     , (Y.Qty * isnull(C1.Liters * C1.BTTLS_PCAS / 9, 1)) AS [9LCasesQty]

              FROM (


 SELECT

                                  'SGWS' AS Legacy_Company

                                  ,INV.ITEM AS ITEM

                                  ,SL.Site_State

--                                ,ISNULL(L.Location_ID, (Cast(INV.SITE_ID AS VARCHAR))) AS Location_ID

                                  ,INV.location_id AS Location_ID

                                  ,INV.SITE_ID AS SITE_NBR

                                  ,dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, 1, cast(right(period, 2) + '/01/' + left(period, 4) AS DATE))) AS Posting_Period

                                  ,'EOM_OH_Qty' AS QtyType

                                  ,Sum(MNTH_END_OH) AS Qty


                           FROM dq.edw_monthend_inventory_os_cache INV

                           INNER JOIN (

                                  SELECT DISTINCT Site_Nbr, Site_State

                                  FROM dq.static_Location

                                  ) SL ON INV.Site_ID = SL.Site_Nbr

                           INNER JOIN scm.CI_CORPITEM C ON INV.ITEM = C.ITEM
                           LEFT JOIN (SELECT  MAX(SSN.ITEM) as ITEM
                                 ,SSN.ALTITEM
                                   ,SSN.LOC
                                FROM dq.JDA_SUPERSESSION SSN

                             WHERE

                                           SSN.STATUS_FLG ='A'
                                       GROUP BY SSN.ALTITEM, SSN.LOC )B ON 
                                       B.ITEM =INV.ITEM

                           WHERE [PERIOD] > year(dateadd(month, (0 - 37), getdate())) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, (0 - 37), getdate()))

                                  AND C.SAPSUPPLIER = 100464

                           GROUP BY INV.ITEM, SL.Site_State, INV.SITE_ID, [PERIOD], INV.Location_ID

                            UNION ALL


                           SELECT

                                  'SGWS' AS Legacy_Company

                                  ,INV.ITEM AS ITEM

                                  ,SL.Site_State

--                                ,ISNULL(L.Location_ID, (Cast(INV.SITE_ID AS VARCHAR))) AS Location_ID

                                  ,INV.location_id AS Location_ID

                                  ,INV.SITE_ID AS SITE_NBR

                                  ,dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, 1, cast(right(period, 2) + '/01/' + left(period, 4) AS DATE))) AS Posting_Period

                                  ,'EOM_OO_Qty' AS QtyType

                                  ,Sum([MNTH_END_OO]) AS Qty

                           FROM dq.EDW_MONTHEND_INVENTORY_os_cache INV

                           INNER JOIN (

                                  SELECT DISTINCT Site_Nbr, Site_State

                                  FROM dq.static_Location

                                  ) SL ON INV.Site_ID = SL.Site_Nbr

                           INNER JOIN scm.CI_CORPITEM C ON INV.ITEM = C.ITEM
                           LEFT JOIN (SELECT  MAX(SSN.ITEM) as ITEM
                                 ,SSN.ALTITEM
                                   ,SSN.LOC
                                FROM dq.JDA_SUPERSESSION SSN

                             WHERE

                                           SSN.STATUS_FLG ='A'
                                       GROUP BY SSN.ALTITEM, SSN.LOC )B ON 
                                       B.ITEM =INV.ITEM



                           WHERE [PERIOD] > year(dateadd(month, (0 - 37), getdate())) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, (0 - 37
), getdate()))

                                  AND C.SAPSUPPLIER = 100464

                           GROUP BY INV.ITEM, SL.Site_State, INV.SITE_ID, [PERIOD], INV.Location_ID

                            UNION ALL

                           SELECT

                                  'SGWS' AS Legacy_Company

                                  ,SD.CORP_ITEM_NO AS ITEM

                                  ,SL.Site_State

--                                ,ISNULL(L.Location_ID,(Cast(SD.SITE AS VARCHAR))) AS Location_ID

                                  ,SD.location_id AS Location_ID

                                  ,SD.SITE AS Site_NBR

                                  ,dateadd(day, - 1, dateadd(month, 1, cast(right(SD.POSTING_Prd, 2) + '/01/' + left(SD.POSTING_Prd, 4) AS DATE))) AS Posting_Period

                                  ,'Sales' AS QtyType

                                  ,Sum(SD.QTY_DEC_EQU) AS Qty

                           FROM dq.EDW_SALES_DETAIL_CACHE SD

                           INNER JOIN scm.CI_CORPITEM C ON SD.CORP_ITEM_NO = C.ITEM
                             LEFT JOIN 

                                  (SELECT  MAX(SSN.ITEM) as ITEM
                                 ,SSN.ALTITEM
                                   ,SSN.LOC
                                FROM dq.JDA_SUPERSESSION SSN

                             WHERE

                                           SSN.STATUS_FLG ='A'
                                       GROUP BY SSN.ALTITEM, SSN.LOC )B ON 
                                       B.ITEM = SD.CORP_ITEM_NO
                           INNER JOIN (

                                  SELECT DISTINCT Site_Nbr, Site_State

                                  FROM dq.static_Location

                                  ) SL ON SD.Site = SL.Site_Nbr



                           WHERE SD.POSTING_Prd > year(dateadd(month, (0 - 37), getdate())) * 100 + month(dateadd(month, (0 - 37), getdate()))

                                  AND C.SAPSUPPLIER = 100464

                           GROUP BY SD.Location_ID, SD.CORP_ITEM_NO, SD.POSTING_Prd, SL.Site_State, SD.SITE  ) A

                   LEFT JOIN dq.JDA_SKU_SOURCING SK ON A.ITEM = SK.ITEM

                       AND A.Location_ID = SK.DEST )Y


              LEFT JOIN (

                     SELECT I.Item, I.DESCRIPTN, I.Size, I.BTTLS_PCAS, SC.LITERS, I.BRAND_NAME, I.SUBGROUP_NAME, I.GROUP_NAME, I.SUPERGROUP_NAME, I.SAPSUPPLIER, I.SUPP_NAME, I.SCC, I.UPC

                     FROM scm.CI_CORPITEM I

                     LEFT JOIN dq.STATIC_9L_CONV SC ON I.Size = SC.size

                     ) C1 ON Y.ITEM = C1.ITEM

              LEFT JOIN scm.CI_CORPITEM C ON Y.Item = C.Item
```

No error. Run like before.

Comment: Since this was a syntax error I am voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some formatting would reveal the issue pretty quickly. The line below has )Y for no apparent reason.

```
AND A.Location_ID = SK.DEST )Y
```

Comment: when i take the ) Y I get a bigger error- msg 209 Ambiguous column name

Comment: Well then fix the ambiguous column name. It is nearly impossible for anybody to debug your query because we have no idea what your table structures are or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did what you told me and it ran. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.